# Submit Form to Iframe using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, model-view-controller, reporting-services

I am trying to load a SSRS report with parameters into IFrame using Jquery. I am using Form target to Iframe to load into Iframe but it open it into new window.

Html Code

```
<iframe id="SSRSReportIFrame" class="modal-fix-height" ></iframe>
<form id="SSRSParamPostForm" action="" method="post" target="SSRSReportIFrame"></form>
```

Jquery Code

```
var paramPostForm = document.getElementById("SSRSParamPostForm");
paramPostForm.action = ReportViewerPath + '?rc:Toolbar=true&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Command=Execute&' + ReportName;
paramPostForm.target = "SSRSReportIFrame";
postParamValues.forEach(function (param) {
          //Adding paramters values as hidden controls 
});
paramPostForm.submit();
```

Or some other way to load Parameter SSRS report to load into Iframe except adding parameters into query string.

Answer (score 1):

The **form target** references the IFrame's **name** and not **id**.  You need to add a **name** attribute like below and that should work.

```
<iframe name="SSRSReportIFrame" id="SSRSReportIFrame" class="modal-fix-height"></iframe>
```